# How to convert a string into a property of an axios response?

Tags: javascript, axios

I looked quite a few threads on SO, but couldn't figure it out. I must be missing something really simple.

I want to convert the string field 'field' into a property. How can I do it? I tried with             `response.data.[a.field].map` but it's not working.

```
const apis = [
  {link: 'http://api.stack...', field: 'items'},
  {link: 'https://newsap..', field: 'articles'}
]

apis.forEach((a) => {
    axios.get(a.link)
    .then(response => {
        // if the response comes from the first link I need to use response.data.items,
        // from the second response.data.articles and so on.
        response.data.[a.field].map(... // not working
    })
}
```

I am sending several `ajax requests` and I would like to handle the responses with only one map function. The problem is that the name of the property that contains the data I want to map is different for each API.

Comment: I think what you want is response.data[a.field].map?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

`response.data[a.field].map()`

Answer (score 0):

U can do that by this way also

```
const apis = [   {link: 'http://api.stack...', field: 'items'},   {link: 'https://newsap..', field: 'articles'}, ]

apis.forEach((a)=>{
    axios.get(a.link)
    .then(response=>{
        // if the response comes from the first link I need to use 
         response.data.items,
        // from the second response.data.articles and so on.
        response.data[a.field].map(... 
       // now in this case you are taking the **data** of **a** and after that you are going to access the value of field the same which you did for link i.e a.link 

    }) }
```